# Image/Icon as submit button

Tags: html, css

How to make icon/image to be used as submit button (input)? I mean I have tried input type "image" but then I had white background around the envelope that I want to be my submit button. I would prefer to use '✉' code but I can't get rid off the background around it.

I am using code like this now but it really isn't really what I want

```
<input name="send" value="&#x2709;" type="submit">
```

[that is how it look right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcKSC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<input type="image">` , more info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image

Answer (score 0):

You could use the  with a a class to apply the background image

```
<button class="mybgImage"></button>
```

With the CSS..

```
.mybgImage {
   width: 40px;
   height: 30px;
   background-image {'theNameOfMyBackgroundImage.png'}
 }
```

Comment: Emm.. Is there any possibility to use '✉' ( &#x2709 ) and get it without any area that is attached to this icon and still use it as a button? Because your way will still force me to cut white area around the image in a photo editor.

Comment: i think you might mean this... 
https://plnkr.co/edit/8q9VqvOiXia80bRPd7aQ?p=preview

This article might be useful - https://css-tricks.com/html-for-icon-font-usage/